Running a javascript on a specific page wordpress
I need to run this javascript code on a specific wordpress page.
The code inserted in the "Head", now works on all pages.
What code should I insert?
<script src="https://example.com/code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

I am not a developer, but a newbie.

There's a bunch of ways. Start by reading https://jetpack.com/blog/how-to-add-javascript-to-wordpress/

Because you're new to save a meltdown. Rather than editing functions.php (1 typo and your whole instance goes down). I suggest you either install one of the many code plugins that allow you to target a specific page. Or just add a code module to the content of the page and put your script in there.
